# How do I substitute environment variables when I ouput a file?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'd like to somehow spit out a file (which has env variable references) and substitute the actual values.  This is what I've tried, but as you can see it's not working.  Any ideas?

```
-bash-3.00$ cat vars_file 
${MY_VAR}
-bash-3.00$ export MY_VAR=MY_VALUE; cat ./vars_file | xargs echo
${MY_VAR}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old thread, but this is a recurrent issue.
Here is a solution using bash's `mapfile`:

```
mateus@mateus:/tmp$ cat input.txt
a = $a
b = $b
mateus@mateus:/tmp$ echo a=$a, b=$b
a=1, b=2
mateus@mateus:/tmp$ function subst() { eval echo -E "$2"; }
mateus@mateus:/tmp$ mapfile -c 1 -C subst < input.txt
a = 1
b = 2
```

The bash builtin `mapfile` calls user-defined function `subst` (see -C/-c options) on each
line read from input file `input.txt`. Since the line contains unescaped text, `eval` is used tu evaluate it and `echo` the transformed text to stdout (-E avoid special characters to be interpreted).

IMHO this is a much more elegant than any sed/awk/perl/regex based solution.

Another possible solution is to use shell's own substitution. This looks like a more "portable" way not relaying on `mapfile`:

```
mateus@mateus:/tmp$ EOF=EOF_$RANDOM; eval echo "\"$(cat <<$EOF
$(<input.txt)
$EOF
)\""
a = 1
b = 2
```

Note we use `$EOF` to minimize conflicting cat's here-document with input.txt content.

Both examples from: https://gist.github.com/4288846

**EDIT: Sorry, the first example doesn't handles comments and white space correctly. I'll work on that and post a solution.**
**EDIT2: Fix double $RANDOM eval**

Comment: Have you tested your second solution? Won't each reference to `$RANDOM` generate possibly different numbers? When I type `echo $RANDOM $RANDOM` in a terminal, I get two different numbers.

Comment: You are right. It produces 2 random number and that heredoc will never close. I will edit it to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As described in the same thread at http://www.issociate.de/board/post/281806/sed_replace_by_enviroment_var_content.html, the "proper" solution would be as follows:

```
awk '{while(match($0,"[$]{[^}]*}")) {var=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH -3);gsub("[$]{"var"}",ENVIRON[var])}}1' < input.txt > output.txt
```

`eval` approach is fine, but tends to fail on XML files for instance.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution not tripping over any sorts of "special" characters in the string to expand. I would add an `if var in ENVIRON` and replace a default. Better would be to not replace a thing, but then the while loop does never end.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with script (e.g. file name is `expand.sh`):

```
while read line; do eval echo \"$line\"; done < $1 > $2
```

The script may be called like this:

```
env VAR1=value1 sh expand.sh input_file output_file
```

---

— http://www.issociate.de/board/post/281806/sed_replace_by_enviroment_var_content.html

Comment: any idea how to do this when there's a paren in the file?

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @andersonbd1: I suppose you could replace the parentheses with sed and replace them back later. Otherwise, you might want to consider to remove the accept mark from my answer to get a better awk solution, as the above questions mentions that you can't read the effect with sed.

Comment: I guess sed is my best bet.  It ain't pretty but it'll work.  Thanks TomWij

Comment: You might want to quote that variable: `echo "$line"`. @andersonbd1: what is the context of the parentheses?

Comment: @Dennis: See the last post of the link; with quotes, weird things happen with backslash sequences.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to say that you should use `read -r`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposed solution:

```
eval $'cat <<\002\n'"$(<ifile)"$'\n\002' > ofile
```

`\002` can be replaced with any character or string that doesn't occur in the ifile. To delete any occurrences of the delimiting character in the input file:

```
eval $'cat <<\002\n'"$(tr -d '\002' < ifile)"$'\n\002' > ofile
```

This solution seems to resolve most issues but is notably vulnerable to command injection in the template file through `$(command)` directives.

Answer (score 1):

`$"xxx"` may be a easy way

```
a=$(< file)
eval b=\$\"$a\"
```

then "$b" is the expanded text

Answer (score 1):

There is a gettext utility for this purpose: [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html). It should be present on most non-minimal systems. It's even present in Git Bash for Windows.

Example:

```
$ echo 'I love $CHEESE at $PWD.' | CHEESE=gouda envsubst
I love gouda at C:/GIT.
```

Answer (score 0):

This defines a shell function that uses python to mimic basic shell expansion of ${name} variables. I use it to expand bash variables embedded in sql scripts. Since my file is not a true bash file, you cant use the eval() bash builtin

```
apply_shell_expansion() {
python - << EOF
import os
doc=open('${1}').read()
for k,v in os.environ.items():
  doc = doc.replace('$'+'{'+k+'}',v)
print doc
EOF
}
```

Comment: (1) What do `myvar` and `myvalue` have to do with anything?  (2) You don’t need to say ``${1}``; you can say `$1`.

Comment: removed the myvar=myvalue example as apparently its more confusing than helpful